# Quais as diferenças e vantagens entre "typedef struct" e "struct"?

Tags: c++, struct, typedef

Vi que a declaração de estrutura não é um padrão entre muitos programadores, enquanto uns utilizam o `typedef struct`, outros utilizam apenas `struct`.

- Qual é o mais indicado de se utilizar?
- Tem alguma diferença de desempenho?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em C++ não tem diferença importante (existem alguns *corner cases* mas não se preocupe com isso), toda `struct` é `typedef`*ed* automaticamente (pelo menos se não estiver dentro de uma função, não me lembro se ali acontece o mesmo, vejo pouco sentido). Em C é diferente.

Então não há ganho de desempenho ou qualquer outro, ele aceita o `typedef` em `struct` só por compatibilidade com C.

Em alguns casos (não `struct`) onde o `typedef` ainda é necessário costuma-se recomendar agora o `using` para criar um aliás de nome.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Qual seria a diferença no C?

Comment: Em C só o `typedef` gera um novo tipo.