# Membros de uma estrutura como ponteiros

Tags: c, ponteiro, memória

No código abaixo estou tentando definir uma estrutura cujos membros são ponteiros que serão utilizados para trabalhar com os dados nome, email e idade, todos alocados dinamicamente, de um funcionário. Porém, o programa encerra quando `qtdeFuncionarios > 1`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct funcionario{
    char *nome;
    char *email;
    int *idade;
};

int main() {
    int opcao, qtdeFuncionarios, i;
    printf("1.Cadastrar funcionario\n");
    printf("2.Listar funcionarios\n");
    printf("3.Editar dados de funcionario\n");
    printf("4.Excluir funcionario\n");
    scanf("%d", &opcao);

    if(opcao = 1){
        printf("Quantos funcionarios deseja cadastrar? ");
        scanf("%d", &qtdeFuncionarios);
        struct funcionario *f = (struct funcionario *)malloc(qtdeFuncionarios * sizeof(struct funcionario));

        for(i = 0; i < qtdeFuncionarios; i++){  
            char *nome = (char *)malloc(35*sizeof(char));
            printf("Digite o nome do funcionario %d: ", i);
            scanf("%s", nome );
            strcpy(f[i].nome, nome);

            printf("%s", f[i].nome );

            char *email= (char *)malloc(35*sizeof(char));
            printf("Digite o email do funcionario %d: ", i);
            scanf("%s", email);
            strcpy(f[i].email, email);
            printf("%s", f[i].email );

            printf("Digite a idade do funcionario %d: ", i);
            scanf("%d", &f[i].idade);
            printf("%d", f[i].idade );
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 1):

Tem vários erros. Alguns não exatamente erros, mas que poderia ser melhor.

Preferi usar um `typedef` que cria um tipo e fica muito mais fácil manipulá-lo.

Mudei `idade` para não ter ponteiro porque não faz sentido e de fato no algoritmo não usa como ponteiro, o que provavelmente é o causador do erro descrito na pergunta.

O `if` tinha uma atribuição de valor para a variável e não uma comparação, só deu certo por coincidência, quando continuasse ia dar problema.

Simplifiquei a locação que fazias coisas desnecessárias e que causam problemas.

Eliminei a criação de variáveis desnecessárias, e com isso a cópia desnecessária.

Também protegi a entrada de dados permitindo só entrar a quantidade de caracteres que cabe no *buffer* criado.

Dei nome melhor pra variável. Não tenha preguiça de digitar o nome.

Eu não fiz nada para liberar a memória que alocou com `malloc()`, mas o correto é fazer isso em algum ponto conforme for o adequado. Em exercício pode até não dar problema, mas acostume-se a fazer o certo usando o [`free()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43766/101) mesmo que não precise, até treina o lugar certo e vê se coloca antes da hora ou deixa vazar algo.

Dá pra melhorar mais alguns pontos.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char *nome;
    char *email;
    int idade;
} Funcionario;

int main() {
    int opcao, qtdeFuncionarios;
    printf("1.Cadastrar funcionario\n");
    printf("2.Listar funcionarios\n");
    printf("3.Editar dados de funcionario\n");
    printf("4.Excluir funcionario\n");
    scanf("%d", &opcao);
    if (opcao == 1) {
        printf("Quantos funcionarios deseja cadastrar? ");
        scanf("%d", &qtdeFuncionarios);
        Funcionario *funcionarios = malloc(qtdeFuncionarios * sizeof(Funcionario));
        for (int i = 0; i < qtdeFuncionarios; i++) {  
            funcionarios[i].nome = malloc(35);
            printf("\nDigite o nome do funcionario %d: ", i);
            scanf("%34s", funcionarios[i].nome);
            printf("\n%s", funcionarios[i].nome);
            funcionarios[i].email = malloc(35);
            printf("\nDigite o email do funcionario %d: ", i);
            scanf("%34s", funcionarios[i].email);
            printf("\n%s", funcionarios[i].email);
            printf("\nDigite a idade do funcionario %d: ", i);
            scanf("%d", &funcionarios[i].idade);
            printf("\n%d", funcionarios[i].idade);
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/rtvO4D). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/NoPointerc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/NoPointer.c).

Comment: Incrível! Muito obrigado por todas as colocações. Pode, por gentileza, me falar mais sobre a relevância desse typedef?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/364771/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/397436/101 Quase tudo oque quer saber já tem algo aqui no site.

Answer (score 0):

Seu programa deve estar falhando porque está executando uma série de instruções indefinidas. Ele está alocando memória em alguns momentos mas não está tratando-a corretamente. Seu código está com diversos erros. Segue abaixo meus comentários.

O primeiro erro é que o `if` não está comparando se `opcao` é igual a `1`, mas está atribuindo o valor `1` à variável `opcao`. Deste modo a execução do programa **sempre** executará o código dentro do `if`. O certo seria usar o operador `==`:

```c
if (opcao == 1) {
    ...
```

Depois disso você aloca memória para o nome e email do funcionário mas ao invés de atribuir a memória aos membros você tenta copiar os dados para eles enquanto ainda são inválidos. O correto seria trocar as chamadas `strlcpy()` por simplesmente atribuição dos ponteiros:

```c
f[i].nome = nome; // ao invés de strcpy(f[i].nome, nome);
...
f[i].email = email; // ao invés de strcpy(f[i].email, email);
```

No caso da idade não recomendo usar ponteiro para memória alocada dinamicamente, visto que números inteiros tem tamanho fixo (4 bytes ou 8 bytes geralmente). Recomendo trocar o tipo do membro `idade` de `int *` para simplesmente `int`. Dessa forma a leitura da idade ficaria assim:

```c
struct funcionario{
    char *nome;
    char *email;
    int idade;
};
...
...
    printf("Digite a idade do funcionario %d: ", i);
    scanf("%d", &f[i].idade);
    printf("%d\n", f[i].idade );
```

Por fim você deve-se preocupar em desalocar toda essa memória adquirida. Se seu programa não fizer isso ocorrerá vazamentos de memória (ou *memory leaks*) e em aplicações extensas (que não é o caso do seu exemplo) isso pode ser um problema sério.